# Is it possible to customize dropbox with chooser API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api

I am uploading file to drop-box using **java Script chooser**. But I unable to customize the view of pop up window (hide some buttons). Is there any way to manage drop-box UI....?
my jsp code is below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="erl9eib1827pg2z"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <a id="link"></a>

    <script>
        var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton({
            success: function(files) {
                var linkTag = document.getElementById('link');
                               linkTag.href = files[0].link;
                                linkTag.textContent = files[0].link;
            },
            linkType: "preview"
        });
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chooser is not for uploading files to Dropbox. It's used to gain access to files already in Dropbox.

That code doesn't appear to be JSP (JavaServer Pages). It appears to be HTML and JavaScript.

No, there's no way to customize the UI for the Chooser.

Comment: I guess start with the Java tutorial: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java.

Comment: I was tried with java.But the problem is in web application file upload we can only get file name but not file path.So with java it is asking complete file path.What should i do......?

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question and sharing your Java code.

Comment: i shared it but i didn't get answer to this.